# Is "Kiaan" a Hindu name?

Tags: scripture, name, meaning

If it's a Hindu name, what is its origin and what does it mean? I have read it at multiple places and it means its the name of Lord Krishna, is it true?

[This](https://twitter.com/misranityanand/status/1116158613066780672?lang=en) twitter post says it means How Much?

Comment: I doubt so as Sandhi rule would make it Kyaan. Although I guess it is possible for someone to be names Ki aan